# Shell script doesn't substitute string-variable when passed to pkgbuild

Tags: bash, shell, installation

I'm calling the pkgbuild command on OSX like this:

```
NAME="Product"
IDENTIFIER="com.${NAME}Package"
pkgbuild --identifier "${IDENTIFIER}" --root "${CONTENTROOT}" "Installer.pkg"
```

When I echo `Identifier` I get `com.ProductPackage` as you would expect.
When I run pkgbuild like that, extract the resulting .pkg file and look into the file `PackageInfo` it says something like:

`<pkg-info overwrite-permissions="true" relocatable="false" identifier="com.${NAME}Package" ...`

For some reasons all other parameter than identifier are substituted correctly.

What is going wrong here and how do I fix it?

Comment: Bash only evaluates variables once in a pass... so ${IDENTIFIER} is expanded out, but the ${NAME} is not... you may have to do something like pkgbuild --identifier $(eval "${IDENTIFIER}") --root "${CONTENTROOT}" "Installer.pkg"

Comment: @DrakeClarris: That's incorrect. As shown in the question, `NAME` is expanded when `IDENTIFIER` is assigned. When `IDENTIFIER` is expanded, it already includes the contents of `NAME`. Your `eval` wouldn't work in any case because there's nothing to `eval` (no command or assignment would be included in the contents of `IDENTIFIER` if single quotes were used in its assignment).

Comment: Ouch good point.. think I was over thinking it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can think of that being possible is if you're using single quotes in your assignment like this:

```
IDENTIFIER='com.${NAME}Package'
```

I notice that you mention echoing "Identifier" (note the difference in case). Is this causing you confusion?